# How to invoke model events forcefully

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I written a function, it will trigger whenever model attribute change just like in the following way.

```
modelEvents:{
  "change:Name":"callback1"
},
callback1:function(){
  console.log("This is testing");
}
```

Initially I set `model.set("Name","hi")` so automatically `callback1` was invoked. Again If I set the same value into model, `callback1` not triggering because model attribute not modified. so For this every time I am doing in the following.

```
model.set({"Name":""},{silent:true});
model.set({"Name":"hi"});
```

If I do like above it's working fine, but I want to know is there any option(like `silent`) to forcefully invoke callback.

Thanks.

Comment: model.trigger('change:Name') ? you can manually trigger change event without changing attribute

Comment: were any of the answers below what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the route of passing an option then the only way to accomplish this would be to override the set method with something like this in your Model, although i haven't done testing on this to make sure it would not produce unexpected results.

```
set: function(key, val, options) {
        //call the origonal set so everything works as normal
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, key, val, options);
        current = this.attributes, prev = this._previousAttributes;
        if (typeof key === 'object') {
            attrs = key;
            options = val;
        } else {
            (attrs = {})[key] = val;
        }

        options || (options = {});

        //new option to always trigger the change on an attribute
        if (options.loud) {
            for (var key in attrs) {
                //if the value is the same as before trigger the change
                //otherwise backbone will have already triggered the chage
                if (_.isEqual(prev[key] , attrs[key])) {
                    this.trigger('change:' + key, this, current[key], options);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then to make use of it call the normal set but pass `loud: true`

```
this.model.set({
            name: "Hi"
        }, {
            loud: true
        });
```

here a fiddle that makes use of it http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/ktvj0kgp/
To show that the event is triggered even when the attribute is the same i have added an attribute called renders to show how many times it has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Model.hasChanged for this? basically it will listen for changes in an attribute.

Take a look here.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged

Hope it helps